# How do I create a eloquent Polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a two eloquent models model User and Retailer. I want to create a new model "Task" where there there should be a field "added_by" which can denote either a user or a retailer.

How can I create the migration for Task so that there is a field that can denote either user or retailer?

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
   $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->morphes('added_by');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

How can I create a Task which references a user for example?

```
Task::create([
'product_id' => 1,
'added_by' => ????
]);
```

Also when I get a eloquent instance of task how can i know if the added_by is referencing to a user or a retailer?

Comment: Have you checked the [`Eloquent relationship documentation`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the migration is `$table->morphs(...)`, not `$table->morphes(...)`.

`$table->morphs('added_by')` will create the columns `added_by_id` and `added_by_type`

---

#### Option 1: 1-M Polymorphic Relationships

You need to define some relationships in the `User`, `Retailer` and `Task` models

`User`

```php
class User extends Authenticable
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Task::class, 'added_by');
    }
}
```

`Retailer`

```
class Retailer extends Model
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Task::class, 'added_by');
    }
}
```

`Task`

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['product_id'];
    
    public function added_by()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

[Eloquent Relationships - One to Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

---

To add a `Task` for an `User` or a `Retailer`, you use the relationship method.

```php
$user->tasks()->create(['product_id' => $productId]);

$retailer->tasks()->create(['product_id' => $productId]);
```

[Eloquent Relationships - Inserting and Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

---

#### Option 2: M-N Polymorphic Relationships

The other option is to use a Many to Many Polymorphic Relationship between `Product` and both `User` and `Retailer`

You need to define some relationships in the `User`, `Retailer` and `Product` nodels

`User`

```php
class User extends Authenticable
{
    // Optional
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Task::class, 'added_by');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'added_by', 'tasks')
                    ->using(Task::class)
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

`Retailer`

```
class Retailer extends Model
{
    // Optional
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Task::class, 'added_by');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'added_by', 'tasks')
                    ->using(Task::class)
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

`Product`

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // Optional
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'product_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'added_by', 'tasks')
                    ->using(Task::class)
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

`Task`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class Task extends MorphPivot
{
    public $incrementing = true;

    // Optional
    public function added_by()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    // Optional
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

[Eloquent Relationships - Many to Many Polymorphic Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

---

To associate an `User` or `Retailer` with a `Product` (using `Task` as a morph pivot)

```php
$user->products()->attach($productId);

$retailer->products()->attach($productId);
```

[Eloquent Relationships - Updating Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Fixed a few typos in the M-N relationships.

Comment: in you option 1 , if i query and get a $task how do i know if its added by User or Retailer @IGP

Comment: `$task->added_by` will either return an `User` or a `Retailer`. Another way of knowing is checking the `$task->added_by_type` value. It will be something like `'\App\Models\User'` or `'\App\Models\Retailer'`. [It can be customized](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types)